# Axure RP 10 : Using 3 dropdown to a field (date)

Tags: wireframe, axure

Issues that I am facing right now:

When the user selected the date they want but they changed the day to “–” then change month to something else. The date field will shows the previous day like “05 June 2023” instead of “June 2023”.

This the drop down for day:
[image: drop down for day]

This the drop down for year and month:
[image]

This the picture that will show when the user selected the specific date:
[image]

What I am trying to achieve from my wireframe is when the user select a specific date from the dropdown, the picture will pop out.

The field will show neither DD MM YYYY or MM YYYY